# StreamReader release lock on file

Tags: c#

Hi I found a problem that if I open a file with FileShare.None and then create StreamReader in static class after it read all lines it will also release the file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (
            var fileStream = new FileStream(
                 @"SomeShareFolder\File.txt",
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.None,
                512,
                FileOptions.None))
        {
            var lines = fileStream.ReadAllLines();
    //HERE THE FILE IS ALREADY RELESEAD so other process now if tries to open with FileStream and  FileShare.None there will not be any exception that file is locked
        }
    }
}

public static class FileStreamExtension
{
    public static List<string> ReadAllLines(this FileStream filestream, StringSplitOptions splitOption = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    {
        var strings = new List<string>();

        using (var file = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 512))
        {
            string lineOfText;

            while ((lineOfText = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (splitOption != StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineOfText))
                {
                    strings.Add(lineOfText);
                }
            }
        }

        return strings;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for that is you're `using` block inside `ReadAllLines`.

At the end of that block the `StreamReader` is disposed and that also disposes the underlying `FileStream`.

To avoid that you can pass `leaveOpen = true` to the `StreamReader` (last added `true`, see [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
using (var file = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 512, true))
```

Comment: so the easiest would be to use  new StreamReader("myFilenaem", Encoding.UTF8, true, 512) to avoid this and keep the lock ?

Comment: @kosnkov Please see my updated answer - you can tell it to not do that via a constructor parameter...